# What is a word that means naming an event after it has already happened

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the Great War is called World War 1 after some time. I want to use it like posthumously, but for events instead of people.

Ex: The Great War was _____ known as World War 1.

Comment: What's wrong with using normal words like *later* or *afterwards*? Why do we need some expostfactoly word here?

Comment: @tchrist oh good question, I wanted to get across that it already had a name but it was changed afterwards due to another event. I'm not sure if posthumously connotes something similar, but I get the sense that whatever is being described posthumous happens because of the death.

Comment: @tchrist Because if we had this word, you wouldn't have needed to make up expostfactoly. So we have our first use case.

Comment: I think there is no single word for that. You can use words or phrases like "retrospectively named", "logged and  named", "named and chronicled" or such. Doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: It's still sometimes called the Great War, at least in the UK.

Comment: @StuartF "later known as" doesn't require that the old name was discarded completely, it just means that a new name was added (and likely became more common).

Comment: @Harry I think "later known as" gets that point across. BTW, "posthumously" specifically means "after death", not just some time later.

Answer (score 1):

Epithet

An add-on name used to characterize a person or thing, that can be used in place of the original name.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epithet

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epithet